# Python on Raspberry Pi/Using Plotly to graph 5 temperatures . x values duplicated in data. Updating every minute. Not streaming. fileopt = "extend"

Tags: python, extend, plotly

I'm recording datafrom 5 temperature sensors using a Raspberry Pi running Python 3.

All is working well and I now want to display plots of the 5 temperatures on one graph, updating every 10 minutes or so. I'd like to use Plotly.

I wrote the following code to test out the idea.

```
#many_lines2

    # tryimg to sort out why x is sent more than once when using extend

    import time

    import plotly.plotly as py
    from plotly.graph_objs import *
    import plotly.tools as tls
    #tls.set_credentials_file(username=, api_key)
    from datetime import datetime


    for count in range  (1,5):

        x1 = count
        y1 = count * 2
        y2 = count * 3
        y3 = count * 4



        trace1 = Scatter(x=x1,y = y1,mode = "lines")
        trace2 = Scatter(x=x1,y = y2,mode = "lines")
        trace3 = Scatter(x=x1,y = y3,mode = "lines")

        data = [trace1,trace2,trace3]

        py.plot (data,filename="3lines6", fileopt = "extend")

        time.sleep(60)
```

See plot and data received by plotly here https://plot.ly/~steverat/334/trace0-trace1-trace2/
See data tab for data received by plotly.

It looksto me as though the x value in the data table has been added three times after the first values were sent.

I cab get the right results by using .append in python to creat lists of values. This leads to long lists, more data to be sent to plotly and seems just wrong.

The code to do this is below and the data on the plotly serve can be found here.https://plot.ly/~steverat/270

```
# using lists and append to send data to plotly

import time

import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import plotly.tools as tls
#tls.set_credentials_file(username='steverat', api_key='f0qs8y2vj8')
from datetime import datetime

xlist = []
y1list= []
y2list = []
y3list = []

for count in range  (1,5):
    xlist.append (count)
    y1list.append (count * 2)
    y2list.append (count * 3)
    y3list.append (count * 4)

    print "xlist = ", xlist
    print "y1list = ", y1list
    print "y2list = ", y2list



    trace1 = Scatter(x=xlist,y = y1list,mode = "lines")
    trace2 = Scatter(x=xlist,y = y2list,mode = "lines")
    trace3 = Scatter(x=xlist,y = y3list,mode = "lines")

    data = [trace1,trace2,trace3]

    py.plot (data,filename="3lines2")

    time.sleep(60)
```

I've searched the web and can find examples where data is streamed but I only want to update the plots every 10 ninsor longer.

Have I missed something obvious???

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Have a look at the "Data" tab at https://plot.ly/~steverat/282/trace0-trace1-trace2/ . I guess that you need to stop adding x three times.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew from Plotly here. Thanks very much for documenting this so well!

### EDIT

This issue should now be fixed, which makes the following workaround obsolete/incorrect. Please don't use the following workaround anymore! (keeping it here for documentation though)

### TL;DR (just make it work)

Try this code out:

```
import time
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import Figure, Scatter
filename = 'Stack Overflow 31436471'

# setup original figure (behind the scenes, Plotly assumes you're sharing that x source)
# note that the x arrays are all the same and the y arrays are all *different*
fig = Figure()
fig['data'].append(Scatter(x=[0], y=[1], mode='lines'))
fig['data'].append(Scatter(x=[0], y=[2], mode='lines'))
fig['data'].append(Scatter(x=[0], y=[3], mode='lines'))

print py.plot(fig, filename=filename, auto_open=False)
# --> https://plot.ly/~theengineear/4949

# start extending the plots
for i in xrange(1, 3):
    x1 = i
    y1 = i * 2
    y2 = i * 3
    y3 = i * 4

    fig = Figure()
    # note that since the x arrays are shared, you only need to extend one of them
    fig['data'].append(Scatter(x=x1, y=y1))
    fig['data'].append(Scatter(y=y2))
    fig['data'].append(Scatter(y=y3))

    py.plot(fig, filename=filename, fileopt='extend', auto_open=False)

    time.sleep(2)
```

### More info

This appears to be a bug in our backend code. The issue is that we reuse data arrays that hash to the same value. In this case your `x` value is hashing to the same value and when you go to extend the traces you're actually extending the *same* `x` array three times.

The fix proposed above has you only extend *one* of the x arrays, which is the same array being used by the other traces anyhow.

Do note that for this to work you *must* supply a non-zero length array in the initial setup. This is because Plotly won't save an array if it doesn't have any data to begin with.

The takeaway is that you'll be A-OK as long as you initialize identical `x` arrays and ensure that in the initialization your `y` arrays aren't also identical to any of the `x` arrays.

Apologies for the inconvenient workaround. I'll edit this response when a fix has been submitted on our end.

Comment: Thanks for this Andrew. I'll post link to plots later. Steve